# LoopbackExempt in UWP apps

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, win-universal-app

Back on Windows 8.x we had a thing called LoopbackExempt that allowed Windows Store Apps to communicate with the local system for development purposes.
This appears to be still present on Windows 10 for UWP apps.
However, adding an exempt does not work (my apps are still not able to communicate with the localhost).

Doing a CheckNetIsolation does not yield and results:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> CheckNetIsolation Debug -n=5bd19b2a-6c63-4dd4-9505-d13f72e46189_ggxdvrfmnj0tt

Network Isolation Debug Session started.
Reproduce your scenario, then press Ctrl-C when done.
      Collecting Logs.....

Summary Report

### Network Capabilities Status

```
InternetClient                Not Used and Insecure
```

### Detailed Traffic Report

```
InternetClient                Not Used and Insecure
```

---

Did they change anything regarding the isolation for UWP? The article to enable the loopback exempt still refers to Windows 8.1?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a heads up: the issue no longer exists and was probably a bug in the preview version.

Visual Studio now automatically enables loopback when running a project in the debugger.